# How do I find all nodes within a grid

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph, grid, gis

I have some questions on keywords/direction for the question I am describing. I will try my best to describe the question below.

I have a map(e.g 4km x 4km) with nodes (as facilities + with GIS location).

I will like to either

**1) Scan a certain fix range of grid (e.g 1km x 1km) on the map and list all nodes in the grid. Ultimately, I will scan the full map range information on the nodes in grid. 
Using 4km x 4km as map range, I will have 4 fixed grid range of 1km x 1km with each grid providing information of the amount of nodes in the 1km x 1km grid.**

OR

**2) Scan all node within the range of one node particular node (e.g 1km radius from the node) and list all nodes in the grid.**

May I know some keywords for me to move forward with my research?

For (1), I have search online and initially thought "occupancy grid" might be what I am looking for but I am not sure yet as it seems to be of different objective than what I am looking for. I am not restricted to the usage of programs but hopefully the function or user-created function might be potentially in matlab.

For (2), listing all nodes with corresponding distance to every other nodes in the grid and filtering all nodes that is within my "range" might be an answer. However, is there any established algorithm to use? I googled and saw a lot of result concerning "Dijkstra's Algorithm" but I think my question is not be a shortest path question.

Personally, I am actually more interested in finding an answer for (1) but in worst case scenario, (2) can potentially be used.
The program that I am using now is matlab and QGIS.

Comment: The ultimate solution will depend a lot on the format of the data. Do you have a matrix of points? or is this, for instance, a nx2 matrix of (latitude,longitude)? or do you have points in Cartesian? We need a few more details.

Comment: Every single point (node) have some type attribute(like type A node, type B node) and have latitude and longitude information that can be drawn on a graph. They are points in Cartesian coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a matrix `A` of nodes in a grid, where each row represents the cartesian coordinates of the nodes in km (or whatever units you want):

```
% Generating random nodes... You can easily make these 3D by changing columns from 2 to 3
A = randn(10,2);
```

Furthermore, suppose we have some reference point `B`, where we want to find all of the nodes within `x` km of `B`

```
% Generating a random reference point
B = randn(1,2);
```

Then the distance vector D between each of the points in A and B is given by

```
D = A - repmat(B,size(A,1),1);
```

and the norm of each of these vectors is given by

```
E = sqrt(sum(D.^2,2))
```

So all of the nodes who lie within x km of B are given by

```
x = 1; % Change to whatever number you want
F = A(E < x,:)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer for (2). I guess the logic you have provided is simple and clear. Just that when I thought to myself that since it is in GPS location coordinate, there might be some accuracy issue if I just treat the distance as Pythagorean distance and not as a earth surface which is spherical. There are some alternative calculation method for calculating distance in matlab mapping toolbox.

Comment: A quick back of the envelope calculation seems to indicate that spherical distance is related to euclidean distance by 2 r * asin(E/(2r)) where r is the earth's radius. If that is indeed the case, then modify E above to read ... 2 r * asin(sqrt(sum(D.^2,2))/(2r))